# Computation of complex valued integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, normal-distribution, complex-integration

I would like to get a simple formula for the complex valued integral
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_Z^2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(iux+\delta d(t)\vert x\vert\right)\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu_Z)^2}{2\sigma_Z^2}\right)\ dx.
$$
This formula is also allowed to contain the cdf $\Phi$ of a standard normal RV. The above integral appears in an ODE I am trying to solve and I would like to avoid solving an integral in each step of my ODE solver. Hence, I would like to have a simple formula for the integral only containing functions that are available in most standard programming libraries.
If I replace $iu$ with $u$, i.e. only consider the real valued case I can simplify the above integral to
$$
-\exp\left((u+\delta d(t))\mu_Z+(u+\delta d(t))^2\frac{\sigma_Z^2}{2}\right)\Phi\left(\frac{(u+\delta d(t))\sigma_Z^2+\mu_Z}{\sigma_Z}\right)\\
-\exp\left((u-\delta d(t))\mu_Z+(u-\delta d(t))^2\frac{\sigma_Z^2}{2}\right)\Phi\left(-\frac{(u-\delta d(t))\sigma_Z^2 + \mu_Z}{\sigma_Z}\right)
$$

However, in the complex case I would need to evaluate the cdf $\Phi$ at a complex number which is implemented in most computer packages like MATLAB. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: $\sigma=\sigma_Z \, ?$. Also what is $\delta d(t)$?

Comment: Yes, $\sigma_Z=\sigma$ (I've edited the question). $d(t)$ is the unknown function in the ODE I am trying to solve. You can just consider it to be a constant when computing the integral. The above integral is one summand in the right hand side of an ODE for $d(t)$.

Comment: And $\delta$ is another constant?

Comment: yes exactly, it is also a constant

Comment: And what do you expect from an answer? If you chuck the integral into Maple or Mathematica you will get an exponential and an error-function. Is that what you want?

Comment: The problem is that when I compute the solution to the ODE in matlab, I have to approximate the integral when defining the vector field for the ODE for $d(t)$. When computing this integral with the MATLAB function "integral" it becomes infinite for large u. In theory however the integral should always be finite. I hoped that using an explicit formula would avoid that.

Comment: I don't think it's nice looking but see yourself:
$$1/2\,{{\rm e}^{1/2\, \left( iu{\sigma}^{2}+\delta\,d{\sigma}^{2}+2\,
\mu \right)  \left( iu+\delta\,d \right) }} \left( 1+ {\rm erf} \left({\frac { \left( iu{\sigma}^{2}+\delta\,d{\sigma}^{2}+\mu \right) }{\sqrt {2}\,\sigma}}\right) \right) \\
+ 1/2\,{{\rm e}^{1/2\, \left( iu{\sigma}^{2}-\delta\,d{\sigma}^{2}+2
\,\mu \right)  \left( iu-\delta\,d \right) }} \left( 1 - {\rm erf} \left({\frac { \left( iu{\sigma}^{2}-\delta\,d{\sigma}^{2}+\mu \right) }{\sqrt {2}\,\sigma}}\right)
 \right) 
$$

Comment: Alright thank you, this is similar to what I derived and still leaves me with the problem that I need to evaluate the error function at a complex value which unfortunately is not implemented in Matlab